# Method for opening a new fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have this method that starts a new activity and it works perfectly, but how would I write something similar for opening a fragment?

```
public void goToInformatica(View v) {
    Intent a = new Intent(this, i.class);
    startActivity(a);
```

usecase;

I have this hamburgermenu that takes me to different fragments, but I want some onscreen buttons to take me to the same fragments. The ID's for the buttons in the menu and the buttons onscreen are the same but because I call the fragments form OnNavigationItemSelected this doesn't work for normal buttons outside of the menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Fragment From Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583205/open-fragment-from-activity)

Answer (score 0):

> you can use below code

```
  protected void setFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
        FragmentTransaction t = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        t.replace(R.id.container_dashboard, fragment, tag);
        t.commit();
    }
```

> `getSupportFragmentManager()` if you are doing fragment transaction
>   from activity
>
> `getFragmentManager()` if you are doing fragment transaction within
>   fragment